# Problem dealing with date/time and timezone

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

I'm creating event series on a Google Calendar based on information from Google Sheets linked to a Google Form. Dealing with dates is a mess and I'm getting erratic results.

I have a field on the spreadsheet with a start DATE shown as `YYYY/MM/DD`
I have a field with a start TIME shown as `HH:mm`
I have a field with an end TIME shown as `HH:mm`

I understand that internally the time has an year/month/day associated and the DATE also has a time associated that are not shown.

I will eventually need to create a calendar event series using the  DATE part from the DATE and the TIME part from the time which I can change using `setHours()` `setMinutes()` methods.

Now my problem is creating a consistent Date object from the DATE cell Value as it seems to change weirdly.

```
var ssTZ = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var SSDate = ss.getRange(6,8).getValue();
var dataStart = Utilities.formatDate(SSDate, 'America/Brasilia' , 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');
var dataStartTZ = Utilities.formatDate(SSDate, ssTZ , 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');
var dataStartSP = Utilities.formatDate(SSDate, 'America/Sao_Paulo' , 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');
var dataStartOS = Utilities.formatDate(SSDate, 'GMT-3' , 'MMMM dd, yyyy 12:00:00 Z');

var date = new Date(dataStart);
var dateTZ = new Date(dataStartTZ);
var dateSP = new Date(dataStartSP);
var dateOS = new Date(dataStartOS);  

Logger.log("Spreadsheet TimeZone: " + ssTZ);
Logger.log(SSDate);
Logger.log("");
Logger.log(date);  
Logger.log(dateTZ);
Logger.log(dateSP);
Logger.log(dateOS);
```

That code produces the following Log outputs:

> [19-07-02 20:39:49:780 BRT] Spreadsheet TimeZone: America/Sao_Paulo
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:781 BRT] Tue Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:782 BRT]
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:784 BRT] Tue Jan 12 10:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:784 BRT] Tue Jan 12 12:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:785 BRT] Tue Jan 12 12:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016
>   [19-07-02 20:39:49:786 BRT] Mon Jan 11 13:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016

which don't make sense since all the timezones used should actually be the same one.

EDIT.... Addedinfo

As requested by @TheMaster the logs from the Text formatted variables are:

```
  Logger.log(dataStart);  
  Logger.log(dataStartTZ);
  Logger.log(dataStartSP);
  Logger.log(dataStartOS);
```

> [19-07-03 12:39:33:099 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 +0000
>
> [19-07-03 12:39:33:100 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 -0200
>
> [19-07-03 12:39:33:100 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 -0200
>
> [19-07-03 12:39:33:100 BRT] January 11, 2016 12:00:00 -0300

The first 3 outputs as explained by @ziganotscha are due to summer time change  to GMT-2 and America/Brasilia not beign recognized as valid timezone.

I'm still puzzled aout why it changes to January 11 when GMT-3 specified as Timezone.

Furthermore if i build the Date object directly from the cell value without formatting I get another diferent time:

```
var rawDate = new Date(SSDate);
```

> 19-07-03 12:39:33:101 BRT] rawDate: Tue Jan 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)

I hate dealing with Dates... so confusing...

EDIT 2 ... More issues with time.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Passeios");
  var timeStart = ss.getRange(6,4).getValue();
  var timeEnd = ss.getRange(6,5).getValue();
  var ssTZ = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

  Logger.log("timeStart: " + timeStart );
  Logger.log("timeEnd: " + timeEnd);


  var dateStart = ss.getRange(6,8).getValue();

  var dateStartObj = new Date(Utilities.formatDate(dateStart, 'ssTZ' , 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'));

var timeStartObj= new Date(Utilities.formatDate(timeStart, 'ssTZ' , 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'));

var justTimeStart = Utilities.formatDate(timeStart, ssTZ, 'HH:mm');


Logger.log(" Time Start Object: " + timeStartObj);
Logger.log("Time Start Object Hours: " + timeStartObj.getHours());
Logger.log("Time Start Object Minutes: " + timeStartObj.getMinutes());

Logger.log("Start Time HH:mm: " + justTimeStart)

var hourStart = Utilities.formatDate(timeStart, ssTZ, 'HH');
var minutesStart = Utilities.formatDate(timeStart, ssTZ, 'mm');
var hourEnd = Utilities.formatDate(timeEnd, ssTZ, 'HH');
var minutesEnd = Utilities.formatDate(timeEnd, ssTZ, 'mm');


Logger.log(" TimeZone :" + ssTZ);
Logger.log(hourStart);
Logger.log(minutesStart);
Logger.log(hourEnd);
Logger.log(minutesEnd);
```

Produces the following log

> timeStart: Sat Dec 30 1899 07:06:28 GMT-0300 (BRT)
>
> timeEnd: Sat Dec 30 1899 07:36:28 GMT-0300 (BRT)
>
> Time Start Object: Sat Dec 30 1899 07:06:28 GMT-0300 (BRT)
>
> Time Start Object Hours: 7
>
> Time Start Object Minutes: 6
>
> Start Time HH:mm: 07:00
>
> TimeZone :America/Sao_Paulo
>
> 07
>
> 00
>
> 07
>
> 30

The Spreadsheet cell is formatted as HH:mm and it shows 
07:00 for start time
07:30 for end time

As you can see there is some 6 minutes and 28 seconds offset that I am not sure where is coming from when logging the cell value or when constructing a Date() object with the cell value.

Formating the cell to just Hours or just Minutes or HH:mm does not carry that offset.

Comment: Log `SSDate, dataStart,dataStartTZ, dataStartSP,dataStartOS` instead

Comment: This is the log for those:Logger.log(dataStart);  

    Logger.log(dataStartTZ);
    Logger.log(dataStartSP);
    Logger.log(dataStartOS); 


19-07-03 12:27:40:438 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 +0000
[19-07-03 12:27:40:439 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 -0200
[19-07-03 12:27:40:440 BRT] January 12, 2016 12:00:00 -0200
[19-07-03 12:27:40:440 BRT] January 11, 2016 12:00:00 -0300

Comment: What's your script timezone? File> project settings ?

Comment: My script timezone is (GMT-03:00) Sao Paulo

But I guess the date I'm using in january is set to GMT-02:00 because at that date summertime was in place and indeed Sao Paulo Time was GMT -02:00 at that moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Spreadsheet time `SSDate` is

> Tue Jan 12 00:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016

i.e., Jan 12 start at midnight in timezone -2 hours from GMT.

`'America/Brasilia'` is not a valid timezone and can be ignored.

Both, `America/Sao_Paulo` and `ssTZ` as the second argument to `Utilities.formatDate()` produces the same valid date

> January 12, 2016 00:00:00 -0200

When the offset is `GMT-3`, it is -3 hours  from midnight GMT,  or -1 hour from GMT-2 timezone, the date is

> January 11, 2016 23:00:00 -0300

i.e., 11pm on the previous day.

#### Issue:

Your logs ignore the time part of date because you provided a static time format for all the dates `12:00:00 Z` instead of `HH:mm:ss`.

So,  for example, the last date formatted on `GMT-3` becomes

> January 11, 2016 12:00:00 -0300

Calling a new Date() changes the above object to local time `GMT-2`(+1 from GMT-3):

> Mon Jan 11 13:00:00 GMT-02:00 2016

Note that  parsing using `new Date(timestring)` is strongly discouraged.

#### References:

- [Timezone format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)
- [Javascript#date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: That makes more sense...
I had not realized that 12:00:00 instead of HH:mm:ss would produce such behaviour.
I am indeed trying to use Date() constructors using individual component values but because I'm using dates and times from different cell values I needed to understand the erratic Date() behaviour I was getting.
This helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: I'vejust updated the post with some other weird behaviour on the Time part this time.

Comment: @Pablo Kindly ask a new question

Comment: Just posted new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296496/weird-time-offset-dealing-with-date-time-and-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion about time zones:

Your time zone is the `'America/Sao_Paulo'` time zone - this is why `Logger.log(dateTZ);` and `Logger.log(dateSP);` give you the same time - as you expect.

However, keep in mind that in January Sao Paulo observes the Brasilia Summer Time (`UTC−02` instead of `UTC−03`), This is where the difference between `Logger.log(dateSP);` and comes `Logger.log(dateOS);` from.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brt

As for dataStart - you assign it the time zone `'America/Brasilia'`, which is not a defined name for a time zone. This is why Apps Script is not accepting the value and gives you `UTC+0` timezone.

You can verify that formatDate() uses the time zone as specified by Java SimpleDateFormat:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

And java uses the  Olson Timezone Database.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html#worldwide
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil

Comment: I though summertime was involved on the first 2, but I still do not understand why GMT-3 changes the day from Jan12 to Jan 11 @ 13:00

I also could not call getTimeZone() or setTimeZone() methods on google script, not sure why...

I get "TypeError: Cannot find function getTimeZone in object"

Comment: And...  if I build the Date() from the original cell value without formatting i get a different time...

 var rawDate = new Date(SSDate);
Logger.log("rawDate: " + rawDate);
LOG OUTPUT: rawDate: Tue Jan 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)