# Google Sheets keep Time format with Datetime data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Details**

In my Google Sheet I have a column that has been formatted in the `03:59 PM` format. When I insert time into it, the data is correctly formatted as `00:00 AM` automatically, but not with the correct date, as it says it's from the year 1899.

When I insert data and specify the date first, it overwrites the columns `00:00 AM` format and instead inserts a `MMM DD YYYY 00:00` format with the month being text, day and year in numbers, and no AM or PM. When I manually format the cell (or whole column) again with `03:59 PM` format, it shows the right time format *and* has the correct date.

I'm currently adding data via a Python script with the Gspread module. This allows me to format it with a specified pattern. The data is added to a cell as a date time string, which then changes the cell's formatting, but then immediately after that individual cell is overridden again into a `hh:mm AM/PM` pattern format: `{"numberFormat": {"type": "DATE_TIME", "pattern": "hh:mm AM/PM"}}`.

Therefore right now only when manually typing in data, it isn't overridden immediately after like the Python script.

**Question**

How can I insert data into a sheet that has a date time property (or at least contain both the date and time), *while* not overwriting the column's `00:00 AM` formatting?

**Have tried:**

- Formatting the entire column and then entering data
- Entering data with various formats, like `12/12/2021 3:00 PM` which adds the PM but still overwrites just the time format.

[image]

Comment: Why not just enter and format later?

Comment: Because I want to automatically add an entry to this sheet every day, and not manually re-format it.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by `automatically`? `onEdit` won't work, if the input is from Python

Comment: Just edited the original question given some more details. I'm not that familiar with apps-script, but onEdit might do the trick. Will have to figure out how to edit only manual data though, instead of re-formatting an individual cell twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rather clumsy solution, but probably it will work for you:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2) return; // if it's not column B do nothing

  var value = e.range.getDisplayValue();
  if (value.length < 12 && value.length > 0) {
    var tz = Session.getTimeZone();
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + ' ' + value), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a');
    e.range.setValue(date);
    e.range.setNumberFormat('hh:mm am/pm');
  }
}
```

It sets current year, month and day for any 'date' that is shorter than 12 letters (it supposes that this 'date' is a time).

Probably you want to move the last line `e.range.setNumberFormat('hh:mm am/pm');` down, out of `{}`. In this case it will format all inputted 'dates' as time `hh:mm`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2) return; // if it's not column B do nothing

  var value = e.range.getDisplayValue();
  if (value.length < 12 && value.length > 0) {
    var tz = Session.getTimeZone();
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd a');
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + ' ' + value), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a');
    e.range.setValue(date);
  }
  e.range.setNumberFormat('hh:mm am/pm');
}
```

**Update**

Here is a little bit less clumsy variant of the same solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 2) return; // if it's not column B do nothing

  var date = e.range.getValue();

  if (date.getFullYear() < 1990) {
    var time = e.range.getDisplayValue();
    var tz = Session.getTimeZone();
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd a');
    var new_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + ' ' + time), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
    e.range.setValue(new_date);
  }

  e.range.setNumberFormat('hh:mm am/pm');
}
```

It changes year, month, day to current date if the automatically assigned year less than 1990.

Comment: I don't think you need to format date at all. Just `setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hh:mm am/pm')`

Comment: Hm... @TheMaster I failed to implement it. What do you mean? Can you show a working piece of code. In my code the formatting is need to get the two strings: 'yyyy-MM-dd' and 'hh:mm am/pm' then I concatenate them to get correct date. Frankly, I'm not an expert in Data.object, to say the least. And I hope there is a more efficient solution. It would be great if you provide it.

Comment: I didn't fully see your concatenation. I'm sure you can directly work with date objects though. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/how-to-read-the-correct-time-duration-values-from-google-spreadsheet

Comment: I think something like this will work: ```const [h, m, s] = ['Hours','Minutes','Seconds'].map(s => e.range.getValue()[`get${s}`]()); e.range.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(h,m,s,0)))```

Comment: @TheMaster my 'concatenation': new Date(**today + ' ' + time**) (`today` and `time` are strings here). As for the rest -- that's the nice trick, thank you, but I still can't see how it helps to solve the task: to get '12/15/2021 03:00 AM' when you input '3:00 AM'. By default it gets '12/30/1899 03:00 AM'. And it changes the hh:mm (in my timezone, at least) if you try to change the year from '1899' to '2021' directly via `date.setFullYear('2021')`

Comment: I mean we're not trying to setFullYear on the original date(while that is possible), my code is trying to copy `3:00`[3h,00m,0s] to a ``new date()``,If timezone is not a issue , i.e., at least h,m,s are preserved on the original date. If tz changes, we need to fix session tz to spreadsheet tz.

Comment: @TheMaster Well. Now I get it. It changes hh:mm (instead of year) in more neat way. But it looks like I have the hasty troubles with timezones (my timezone Moscow, Russia GMT+03, and I have no idea about daylight saving, probably it's there as well). I just tried your code https://pastebin.com/qZa0exeh (in new spreadsheet) and when I'm input '22:22' it gets me the date '12/15/2021 22:51:43' (time offset 29 min 43 sec! probably it has to do with dates in Russian Empire around 1900s). This is exactly why I prefer to use strings. I would be grateful if you show me, how it should be done properly.

Comment: @TheMaster from this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296496/weird-time-offset-dealing-with-date-time-and-timezone I tend to think that to play with strings (getDisplayValue(), etc) is still the most reasonable solution for such cases. At the end of the day. :)

Comment: I agree it's probably the easiest in this case, but generally, you should avoid strings as dates. Even in this case, I would probably suggest using dates. I think  probably using a offset based on the date `new Date(1899,11,30)` will work in all cases, but I didn't test it and I don't want to waste your time more too. If I do test and find a way, I'll add a comment or edit/add a another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clear `B2:B` and in `B2`:

```
={A2:A}
```

You can then enter the full date in `A2:A` and see expected formatting in `B2:B`

- Raw data:     `A2:A`
- Presentation: `B2:B`

You can  also separate raw data and presentation to separate sheets.

Comment: That's not what I was going for since this sheet is used for data input and presentation already, not raw data, so 2 columns isn't ideal in this case.

Comment: @Nuxurious Since you tagged script, I guess you were going for a `onEdit` script. Can you provide what you've tried in scripting so far?

Comment: Nothing in scripting yet, but in a Python automation I've been able to reformat with the right pattern when inserting a date time string. This way, it inserts the string, changes the column's formatting, but then reformats the cell immediately again. But this isn't the case for manual input yet.